# ImportError: No module named readonly

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error when i do python manage.py check. I have changed my virtual env mode to 755. Any other ideas you may have?

```
Your environment is:"onadata.settings.onadata_settings"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named readonly
```

Comment: Did you check in the enviroment if the module was available

Comment: go to this directory /home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/ and see if there is a python programm with the name readonly.py or readonly.pyc

Comment: It can also be in '/home/webserver/virtual_environments/onadata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' you to search if it is available in package environment

Comment: hi! no such file (readonly.py or readonly.pyc)

Comment: So what module did you install for this programm